# How to display the static block inside tab content?

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-block, tabs

I want to insert a cms block in a tab content. So I inserted the below code in `catalog.xml`:

```
<block type="cms/block" name="care" as="care" >  
   <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
   <action method="setBlockId" translate="value"><block_id>Care</block_id></action>
</block>
```

But the block is not displayed in the tab content. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code to add CMS block as TAB :

```
<block type="cms/block" name="care" as="care" >  
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>CMS block Title</value></action>
    <action method="setBlockId" translate="value"><block_id>Care</block_id></action>
</block>
```

Comment: yes it is working. Thank you. Do you know how to hide that `product collateral` tab when there is no content? If you know kindly help please.

Comment: Please raise a new question, it's hard to show here in comments

Comment: okay. If you know kinly help me. I will raise it as new qeustion. Thank you for your response. I have upvoted and accepted your answer.